Question wrongly closed for being a homework question
Trouble with formula $F_{net} = m*a_{com}$
This is, to me, clearly not a homework question. While it does include a homework problem, it's pretty clear that the question Abel is asking is not copied from the textbook. Most such questions require the student to calculate the horizontal acceleration of $m_1$, or some sort of value. Abel's question is because they have gaps in their misunderstanding, and does not ask us to calculate a value for him. I believe it's on topic.

I've marked this as "completed" since the question has been reopened.
